# Where to place a socket within a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails-based WebApp and a unity-based App. These have to communicate with each other over a UDP-Socket.

Where is the best place within the rails App to create such socket? For me its necessary that the **socket already exist before an user visits the webapp** and the socket is **accessible within a controller**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails files under `config/initializers` get loaded when the application starts.

So one way to do what you want is to create a new file there that initializes the socket connection and assign it to a constant which the rest of the application uses.

```
class Utility
  def self.socket_connection
    @connection ||= connect_socket
  end

  def self.connect_socket
    # Your logic for connecting the socket
  end
end
```

And later when you need the connection just use `Utility.socket_connection`

If this is "real" application, you probably need more sophisticated approach that:

- pools the connections to handle when different parts of the applications want to use socket connections at the same time. (They'd check out & in the connection, similarly how ActiveRecord's [`#with_connection`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/107f4282bbfabc011d5ad3bcf3fb3c6fb812ad30/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L289) works
- monitor the connections, closing and re-establishing them as necessary

Comment: Thank you dude! A file within conf/initializers was what I was looking for.

Comment: `config/initializers` is the name of the directory, I believe